# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE fails only on the first record's key (auto_increment) -- bug?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Here's the content of a very simple text file to show my problem. Somehow, I end up using "|" as the separator. But that's not the problem...

```
10|Antonio
11|Carolina
12|Diana
13|Alejandro
```

Here is the code I use to create that very simple table and to load the file into it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names 
(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\Users\\Carolina\\Desktop\\Tmp\\TablasCSV\\names.csv' 
INTO TABLE names 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Here is the result of a simple select:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM names;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Antonio   |
| 11 | Carolina  |
| 12 | Diana     |
| 13 | Alejandro |
+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It has worked fine for me until I encounter the case, in which the first record value for the "id" was not "1".

I always get "1" after the load.

Any one has noticed this problem?
Is this a bug?

So far, I am fixing the record using an UPDATE command after the load, but I don't like it!!!!

Comment: Can you give us a completely reproducible example?  According to the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), there should be nothing wrong with manually assigning values to an auto increment column.  But, if the column is auto increment, do you really care about which values MySQL would assign?  You could try not inserting the auto increment values from your file, and that by itself might fix your problem.

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: I am using "Server version: 5.7.14-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)"   I am migrating data on several tables, with foreign keys. I do care about the values,

Comment: I tried using: id INT, instead of: id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, and now I get 0 on the first row value for id.